# Create an exe without python environment in pyinstaller?

Tags: pyinstaller

I want to create an exe of my Python script without including the Python environment and its packages using pyinstaller. The system running the exe file already has the python environment and all the packages installed.

I tried excluding a few packages by using the exclude command but not able to find any ways to exclude the python environment.

Comment: PyInstaller always uses its own Python environment when running the executable. If you don't need that you can simply ship `*.pyc` files. Also, why?

Comment: If the system already has the python enviorneent then what is the point of creating the exe?